# What's the difference between ScreenToWorldPoint and ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What's the difference between ScreenToWorldPoint and ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle? And when should we use which one?

Senario:
I'm using UI system creating my card game similar to Hearthstone. I want to transform my mouse drag positions to world position. `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(UIObjectBeingDragged.transform.parent as RectTransform, Input.mousePosition, Camera.main, out resultV3)` works fine. But I also tried `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)`, and it give a different and "wrong" result.

Comment: So in general why not use what already works? ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

Gives you a world position (the return value) that is along a ray shot through the near plane of the camera (the `Camera` whose method is being called) at some given point (the x and y components of the `position` parameter) and a given distance from that near plane (the z component of the `position` parameter).

You should use this when you:

1. have a specific distance from the near plane of the camera you are interested in and
2. don't need to know if it hit inside some rectangle or not

You could think of this as a shortcut for [`Ray.GetPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.GetPoint.html) that uses the x and y of `position` and various info of the `Camera` to make the `Ray`, and the z component of `position` is the `distance` parameter.

## [`ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle.html)

Also gives you a world position (`worldPoint`) along a ray shot through the near plane of a camera (`cam`) at a given point (`screenPoint`). Only this time instead of giving you the point a given distance along the ray, it gives you the intersection point between that ray and a given rectangle (`rect`) if it exists, and tells you if such an intersection exists or not (the return value).

You should use this when you:

1. have a specific rectangle you are interested in the intersection with a camera ray,
2. You don't know the distance between the camera or its near plane and the intersection point
3. Want to know if that rectangle is hit by the ray or not.

You could think of this as a shortcut for [`Plane.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html) which uses `cam` and `screenPoint` to make the `Ray`, and `rect` to make the `Plane`, and also gives some more information of if it would intersect outside the boundaries of the rect.

Comment: Thank you! In my case I think I can use either one of them, right? But why does "ScreenToWorldPoint" gives a different result? Both should transform my mouse's position on screen to world position.

Comment: World position isn't two dimensional so depending on the camera's position, rotation and the z value for `position` in `ScreenToWorldPoint` vs the rects position and rotation for `ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle` The result could be very different. For just one example, if you have 10000 for the z component in `ScreenToWorldPoint` but the rect is directly in front of the camera for `ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle` , they would be very different.  If this answer helped, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359)!

Comment: Thank you! In my project, the camera's z and the rect distance to camera are different, and I did rotate the camera's x to 90 to (the canvas is set to Screen Space - Camera). But I still don't get why the x and y are different when calling `ScreenToWorldPoint` and `ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle`. Since the mouse position is fixed, and the world coordinates are the same, they should give out the same x and y in my opinion.

Comment: Plus they both provided the Camera.main. The Camera's position is (0, 4.75, 0) rotation is (90, 0, 0). The canvas' plane distance is 4.75. I test it, for example if the mouse position is (642.7, 834.7, 0.0), then `ScreenToWorldPoint` gives (0.0, 4.8, 0.0) and `ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle` gives (0.3, 0.0, -0.4).